# Import photos from photo gallery to resources folder of xcode (Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am working on an IPad app in xcode. In the IPad simulator, I have got some photos in its photo gallery. How can I add one of those photos into my resources folder of the xcode ?? Is it at all possible ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see these threads

[Bundles and file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916824/iphone-bundles-and-file-access)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1731074?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

It is a file like any other that resides on your hard drive. The path to the simulator will look something like this:

```
Users/INSERT_YOUR_USER_HERE/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/
```

Dig around those directories until you find you app, copy the file and then add it to your XCode project.